# Как определить четность числа в Python при помощи побитовых операций?

Tags: python-3.x, битовые-операции

Как определить четность числа в Python при помощи побитовых операций?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вариант #1** (самый простой):

```
x = 5
if x & 1:       
   print "Наш x - нечетный"
else:
   print "Наш x - четный"
```

Здесь всё просто, мы наше двоичное представление 5 (`101`) сравниваем с двоичным представлением 1 (`001`), через побитовое И. В итоге получаем `001`, что будет больше нуля, значит последний символ в двоичном представлении - 1 (вся суть такой проверки, выяснить, последний символ у нас `1` (нечетное) или `0` (четное).

**Вариант #2** (интересный):

Смотрите. Есть операция побитовых сдвигов.

```
x = 5
x >> 1 # = 2; равносильно делению на 2 без остатка
x << 1 # = 10; равносильно умножению на 2
```

Учитывая это, можно проверить так:

```
x = 5
y = x >> 1
if x == (y << 1):
   print "Наш x - четный"
else:
   print "Наш x - нечетный"
```

Чтобы понять, как работает побитовый сдвиг, нужно вспомнить, что числа представляются нулями и единицами. Наш `x` равен `5`, тогда его двоичное представление будет таким: `101`.

Сдвиг вправо (`>>`) - это, можно сказать, удаление количества нулей или единиц справа двоичного представления соответствующего числу после оператора. В нашем случае - 1. Т.е. получается `10`, что соответствует 2 в десятичном представлении.

Сдвиг влево - это добавление нулей справа. Мы, как будто двигаем двоичное представление влево, на N символов, эти N символов заполняются нулями. Т.е. получившиеся `10` мы "сдвигаем на 1", и получаем `100`, что соответствует 4-м в десятичном виде. В итоге у нас в `if` будет сравнение чисел `4` и `5`.